# PHP file_put_contents textarea issue

Tags: php, textarea, fopen, fwrite

Having an issue reading/writing via PHP file_get_contents/file_put_contents. Basically I want to read the text file into a textarea (click Edit File button) and be able to edit it and submit the alterations (Submit Changes button) and redraw textarea with new file contents.

It reads fine.

It removes all the file's content, not overwrite/update it, leaving a blank file.

Seems like its unable to take the textarea contents and input them as the new contents of the file. I know its something trivial and I am missing it.

Running on a Win Apache server.

CODE:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="form" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="pickedName" value="Edit File" />&nbsp;
<input name="file_picked" value="1.txt" type="text" id="file_picked" style="width:250px;" />&nbsp;
<input type="submit" name="submitChanges" value="Submit Changes">
</form>

<?php
$file_picked = $_POST['file_picked'];
$edit_field = $_POST['edit_field'];

if (isset($_POST['pickedName'])) {
//get file contents and display in textarea box
$theData = file_get_contents($file_picked);
echo "<textarea name=\"edit_field\" id=\"edit_field\" cols=\"150\" rows=\"30\">";
echo $theData;
echo "</textarea><br />";
}

if (isset($_POST['submitChanges'])) {
//grab new textarea contents and put into file.
$theData = file_put_contents($file_picked, $edit_field);

//redraw textarea with new contents
$theData = file_get_contents($file_picked);
echo "<textarea name=\"edit_field\" id=\"edit_field\" cols=\"150\" rows=\"30\">";
echo $theData;
echo "</textarea><br />";

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Your `<textarea>` is outside of the `<form>...</form>` block. Why its value won't be received. Enable `error_reporting`.

Comment: I tried this prior as I had wondered about this. I can get that to work however it shows two textarea boxes. The original form and the one I call on button press. Definitely a step in the right direction.

Comment: You know you could just move the `</form>` to the bottom HTML block.

Comment: That would make WAY too much sense. /facepalm. Thank you. Problem solved.

Comment: Thats not the only problem ... to many code duplication too

Answer (score 0):

Use FILE_APPEND flag to the file instead of overwriting it

```
file_put_contents($file_picked, $edit_field, FILE_APPEND);
```